# Calculating edit distance on successive rows of a `Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, nlp

I have a data frame as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

// some data...
val df = Seq(
  (1, "AA", "BB", ("AA", "BB")),
  (2, "AA", "BB", ("AA", "BB")),
  (3, "AB", "BB", ("AB", "BB"))
).toDF("id","name", "surname", "array")

df.show()
```

and i am looking to calculate the edit distance between the 'array' column in successive row. As an example i want to calculate the edit distance between the 'array' entity in column 1 ("AA", "BB") and the the 'array' entity in column 2 ("AA", "BB"). Here is the edit distance function i am using:

```
def editDist2[A](a: Iterable[A], b: Iterable[A]): Int = {
  val startRow = (0 to b.size).toList
  a.foldLeft(startRow) { (prevRow, aElem) =>
    (prevRow.zip(prevRow.tail).zip(b)).scanLeft(prevRow.head + 1) {
      case (left, ((diag, up), bElem)) => {
        val aGapScore = up + 1
        val bGapScore = left + 1
        val matchScore = diag + (if (aElem == bElem) 0 else 1)
        List(aGapScore, bGapScore, matchScore).min
      }
    }
  }.last
}
```

I know i need to create a UDF for this function but can't seem to be able to. If i use the function as is and using Spark Windowing to get at the pervious row:

```
// creating window - ordered by ID
val window = Window.orderBy("id")

// using the window with lag function to compare to previous value in each column
df.withColumn("edit-d", editDist2(($"array"), lag("array", 1).over(window))).show()
```

i get the following error:

```
<console>:245: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName
 required: Iterable[?]
       df.withColumn("edit-d", editDist2(($"array"), lag("array", 1).over(window))).show()
```

Comment: `editDist2` is not `udf`  (you have to wrap it with `udf`), required type for `ArrayType` is `Seq[_]` and the whole thing won't scale (orderBy only window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out you can use Spark's own levenshtein function for this. This function takes in two string to compare, so it can't be used with the array.

```
// creating window - ordered by ID
val window = Window.orderBy("id")

// using the window with lag function to compare to previous value in each column
df.withColumn("edit-d", levenshtein(($"name"), lag("name", 1).over(window)) + levenshtein(($"surname"), lag("surname", 1).over(window))).show()
```

giving the desired output:

```
+---+----+-------+--------+------+
| id|name|surname|   array|edit-d|
+---+----+-------+--------+------+
|  1|  AA|     BB|[AA, BB]|  null|
|  2|  AA|     BB|[AA, BB]|     0|
|  3|  AB|     BB|[AB, BB]|     1|
+---+----+-------+--------+------+
```

Comment: Nice to know this.

Comment: You should answer your own question then by ticking it as well.